# finding nearest value in a array in pinescript v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

i am trying to code a strategy based on fibretracement. i have added the fib values as an array. i want for trail my target and stoploss basis the fib levels.
if close of the candle is between fib levels say 0.5 and 1, the trail target i want to fix as fib level of 1 and stoploss at 0.5. then if close moves to 1.25 of fib level, then the target to be moved to the 1.618 and tsl at 1.
hence i am looking to get a positioning of close[1] in respect to the array index say between index position 3 and 4 or say 5 and 6 and out put to be the value of the respective index iteratively.
i have made this work thru a if loop

```
if target > fiblevel1
t1 := fiblevel2
sl  := fiblevel1
    if target > fiblevel2
        t1:=fiblevel3
        sl:= fiblevel2
```

and so on.
i am trying to do the same thru array manipulation if possible
can some body help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var float[] array_fibos = array.new_float()
var bool level_reached = false

// fill the array with fibo levels
array.push(array_fibos, fiblevel1)
array.push(array_fibos, fiblevel2)
array.push(array_fibos, fiblevel3)
...

// sort the array
// for longs, ascending order
// for shorts, descending order

// use array.sort function

// browse the array and exit when high is higher

if array.size(array_fibos) > 0

    for i = 0 to(array.size(array_fibos) == 0  ? na : array.size(array_fibos) - 1)

        if high >= array.get(array_fibos, i)
             level_reached := true
             break
```

Comment: hi thanks bro. the soloution works